# profiling inside a python function

Tags: python, python-2.7, profiling

I am trying to profile a python script, I have identified the bottleneck to be a  function using python -m cProfile myscript.py. How do I know which line in the function is the cause for the bottle neck? Can I profile line by line inside a function?
Thanks!

Comment: The code is a bit long, hence didn't want to add it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [line profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/line_profiler/) package that you use for this.